# Is there any way to convert case-sensitive hashtable into case-insensitive hashtable?

Tags: powershell

I have a case-sensitive hashtable, and I want to convert it into case-insensitive.

I know [PowerShell is basically case-insensitive in nature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_case-sensitivity?view=powershell-7.3).
However, that is not the case in Azure PowerShell command.

For example, let's say I have a Azure Resource Group "exmapleRG" that has a tag "owner:jdoe@example.com".
`$A` is a case-sensitive hashtable.

```
$A = (Get-AzResourceGroup -name "exampleRG").Tags
$A.Owner # returns nothing
$A.owner # returns jdoe@example.com
```

I want to make it case-insensitive so that I can get values by case-insensitive keys.
(i.e. `$A.Owner # returns jdoe@example.com`, `$A.OWNER # returns jdoe@example.com`)

I tried to filtering keys like below

```
$A = (Get-AzResourceGroup -name "exampleRG").Tags | where-obejct {$_.keys -like "owner"}
```

but nothing changed.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to convert a case-sensitive hash table into a case-insensitive one, the way around it is to recreate it:

```bash
$hash = [hashtable]::new()
$hash['owner'] = 'jdoe@example.com'
$hash.Owner # null

$caseInsensitiveHash = [hashtable]::new($hash, [StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
$caseInsensitiveHash.Owner # jdoe@example.com
```

The [`Hashtable(IDictionary, IEqualityComparer)` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-hashtable-ctor(system-collections-idictionary-system-collections-iequalitycomparer)) will make a copy of the existing hash table passed as argument and use the specified comparer.

Comment: "*It's not possible to convert a case-sensitive hash table into a case-insensitive one*", I don't think that is correct: `[HashTable]::new($Hash,[StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @iRon thank you, i didn't notice the `IDIctionary` overload. Still, that's recreating not converting its recreating