# Powershell case insensitive dictionary

Tags: azure, powershell, hashtable, case-insensitive

I retrieved a list of all Azure resources using `Get-AzResource` and stored one sample record in `$Item`. I am trying to get all of our tags for every resource, but the capitalization of the Key is causing a lot of missed records. I have found a lot of forums stating to create a hashtable differently, but given that I am getting this directly from Azure I am not sure how  exactly to do that. For the example below, I am hoping that `$Item.tags.Environment` will return the value.

```
C:\> $Item

Name              : resourceName
ResourceGroupName : rgName
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Compute/disks
Location          : eastus
ResourceId        : uniqueResourceId
Tags              :
                    Name         Value
                    ===========  =============
                    ENVIRONMENT  Production
                    OWNER        SharedService

C:\> $Item.Tags

Key         Value
---         -----
ENVIRONMENT Production
OWNER       SharedService

C:\> $Item.tags.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Dictionary`2                             System.Object

C:\> $Item.tags.ENVIRONMENT
Production
C:\> $Item.tags.ENVIRONMENt
C:\> $Item.tags.Environment
C:\>
```

Is there any way to make an existing hashtable case insensitive?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75819166/15339544

Comment: I was about to refer to the same issue: `$Tags = [hashtable]::new($Item.tags, [StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Annoying.  The get-azureaduser extensionproperty is the same way.

Comment: `$Item.tags.getenumerator() | ? key -eq environment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new dictionary object with a case-insensitive comparer and copy the entries to that:

```
$tags = @{} # hashtable literals use a case-insensitive default key comparer
# alternatively, pass the desired comparer to a dictionary constructor
# $tags = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,psobject]]::new([StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)

$Item.Tags.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object { $tags[$_.Key] = $_.Value }

# now you can do
$tags['enVirONmeNt']
```